# Is there a formula for the eigenvalues of $\rho_A,\rho_B$ in terms of those of $\rho_{AB}$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, density-operator, quantum-states

Let $\rho_{AB}$ be a bipartite density matrix with marginal states $\rho_A=\text{tr}_B(\rho_{AB})$ and $\rho_B=\text{tr}_A(\rho_{AB})$. In such a case, is there a formula for the eigenvalues of $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ in terms of the eigenvalues of $\rho_{AB}$?

Comment: Indeed. If we fix $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$ there are many such $\rho_{AB}$, but nevertheless there should still be some function of the eigenvalues of $\rho_{AB}$ which yields the eigenvalues of $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$, and moreover, this function should be independent of which $\rho_{AB}$ we choose.

Comment: In case you want an expression involving *only* the eigenvalues of the whole state it won't work. Consider the two states $|00>$ and $|00>+|11>$ -- same eigenvalues (since they are pure), different eigenvalues on the marginals.

Comment: In the case of pure (possibly entangled) states, check out the Schmidt decomposition. While the spectrum of $\rho$ will be different in general from the one of $\rho_A$ or $\rho_B$ as the above counter example shows, the theorem gives you the equality of the spectra of $\rho_A$ and $\rho_B$. In the previous example, the common spectrum would be $(1/2,1/2)$

Answer (score 2):

You cannot in general predict the eigenvalues of the marginals from the eigenvalues of the full state.

For example, the states $\rho=|00\rangle\!\langle 00|$ and $\rho=|\Psi\rangle\!\langle\Psi|$ with $|\Psi\rangle\equiv\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|00\rangle+|11\rangle)$ have the same eigenvalues, but their marginals have different eigenvalues.